# How to make sure a given future completes first in tests?

Tags: scala, testing, concurrency, future

I'm writing tests for function `bar`:

```
def bar(fut1: Future[Int], 
        fut2: Future[Int], 
        fut3: Future[Int]): Future[Result] = ???
```

`bar` returns `Result` like this:

```
 case class Result(
    x: Int,          // fut1 value
    oy: Option[Int], // if fut2 is complete then Some of fut2 value else None 
    oz: Option[Int]  // if fut3 is complete then Some of fut3 value else None 
 )
```

I want to write tests for all test cases:

- `fut1` completed, `fut2` and `fut3` did not complete
- `fut1` completed, `fut2` completed, `fut3` did not complete
- etc.

So I am writing a *fake* implementation of functions `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3` for these tests.

```
def foo1(x: Int): Future[Int] = ??? 
def foo2(x: Int): Future[Int] = ??? 
def foo3(x: Int): Future[Int] = ???
```

Test #1 invokes all these functions, checks if `fut1` completes first, and invokes `bar`

```
val fut1 = foo1(0)
val fut2 = foo2(0)
val fut3 = foo3(0)

// make sure `fut1` completes first
```

Test #2 invokes all these functions, makes sure that `fut2` completes first, and invokes `bar`.
Test #3 invokes all these functions, makes sure that `fut3` completes first, and invokes `bar`.

My question is how to implement the functions `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3` and the tests.

Comment: If they are async, why does it matter in which order they complete?

Comment: @ViktorKlang by the way, very good question, something I should myself ask before trying to find answer.

Comment: @ViktorKlang It matters for tests. I want to test three different use cases. Imagine I am writing tests for `firstCompletedOf`.

Comment: @ViktorKlang I updated the question and realized that you are right and the order of the async operations don't really matter. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome, @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what it is exactly you are trying to test.
If you simply use futures that have already completed, you will get the behavior you describe:

```
def f1 = Future.successful(1)
def f2 = Future.successful(2)
def f3 = Future.successful(3)

eventually {
   Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(f1, f2, f3)).value shouldBe Some(1)
}
```

(note, that you *cannot* compare directly with `fut1` like you did in the question, that'll always be false, because `.firstCompletedOf` returns a new future).

You can also make only one future complete, and leave the others alone:

```
    val promise = Promise[Int].future
    def f1 = promise.future // or just Future.successful(1) ... or Future(1)
    def f2 = Future.never
    def f3 = Future.never
  
    result =  Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(f1, f2, f3))
    promise.complete(Success(1)) 
    eventually {
       result.value shouldBe 1
    }
```

Etc ... Can make the other futures be backed by their own promise too for example, if you want them all to complete eventually (not sure what it'll gain you, but then again, I am not sure what you are testing here to begin with).

Another possibility is make them depend on each other:

```
    val promise = Promise[Int]
    def f1 = promise.future
    def f2 = promise.future.map(_ + 1)
    def f3 = promise.future.map(_ + 2)
    
    ... 
    promise.complete(Success(1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This answer is very useful. You are right it is unclear what I am testing. I will update the question.

Comment: I updated the question and realized that your 2nd suggestion does answer it. The order does not really matter. I can fake `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3` with `Future.successful` and `Future.never`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try attach completeness timestamp to each future via `map`, like:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

def foo1(x: Int): Future[Int] = Future {Thread.sleep(200); 1} 
def foo2(x: Int): Future[Int] = Future {Thread.sleep(500); 2} 
def foo3(x: Int): Future[Int] = Future {Thread.sleep(500); 3}

def completeTs[T](future: Future[T]): Future[(T, Long)] = future.map(v => v -> System.currentTimeMillis())

val resutls = Await.result(Future.sequence(
  List(completeTs(foo1(1)), completeTs(foo2(1)), completeTs(foo3(1)))
), 2 seconds)

val firstCompleteTs = resutls.map(_._2).min
val firstCompleteIndex = resutls.indexWhere(_._2 == firstCompleteTs)
assert(firstCompleteIndex == 0)
```

Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/L9g78DSNQIm2K1jGlQzXBg

Answer (score 2):

You could repurpose [`firstCompletedOf`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L714) to verify whether the future of a given index in the futures list is the first completed one:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Promise}
import scala.util.Try

def isFirstCompleted[T](idx: Int)(futures: List[Future[T]])(
    implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Boolean] = {
  val promise = Promise[(T, Int)]()
  val pRef = new AtomicReference[Promise[(T, Int)]](promise)
  futures.zipWithIndex foreach { case (f, i) => f onComplete { case tt: Try[T] =>
      val p = pRef.getAndSet(null)
      if (p != null) p tryComplete tt.map((_, i))
    }
  }
  promise.future.map{ case (t, i) => i == idx }
}
```

Test running:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val futures = List(
  Future{Thread.sleep(100); 1},
  Future{Thread.sleep(150); throw new Exception("oops!")},
  Future{Thread.sleep(50); 3}
)

isFirstCompleted(0)(futures)  // Future(Success(false))
isFirstCompleted(2)(futures)  // Future(Success(true))
```

For writing test cases, consider using [`ScalaTest AsyncFlatSpec`](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing).